# Fail2Ban Will Not Start

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I am running Centos 6.5 (Kernel Linux jspring 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and I was wondering if someone could assist - Im installing Fail2Ban through yum however when I go to run it I am getting the following error;

```
 service fail2ban start
Starting fail2ban: ERROR  Directory /var/run/fail2ban exists but not accessible for writing
                                                           [FAILED]
```

If anyone could advise me how to fix this that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that could be causing this.

First make sure the permissions and ownership are correct as the other answers state. The directory permissions should be `drwxr-xr-x` (a.k.a. 644) and it should be owned by `root:root`.

Now make sure you are attempting to run the start command with the proper authority. If `service fail2ban start` does not work, try `sudo service fail2ban start`. Using sudo is recommended but you could also switch to or login as the root user.

You may also want to reboot after you get it running and then run `sudo service fail2ban status` to make sure it successfully started up again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropriate rights on the mentioned directory:

drwxr-xr-x root:root

Answer (score 0):

You should set the permissions like this: `chmod -R 644 /var/run/fail2ban/`

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. Explain your thoughts so users can understand what your code means. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned, this is clearly a permissions issue. I'm not sure if this applies to your version but fail2ban in 2018 has a client, run as:

`sudo fail2ban-client start`

(or `restart` or `status`). **It must be run as sudo though.**

Answer (score 0):

As is documented in the official commands list [here](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Commands) the command `fail2ban start <jail>` is clearly used to start jails and not to start `fail2ban`. So you completely missunderstood it's usage.

Try to first stop and then quickly start again the jail `sshd` that is enabled by default:

```
fail2ban-client stop sshd
fail2ban-client start sshd
```

Hey! It works!